# Re-render App component after child component API get request?

Tags: reactjs, components, rendering

A little confused here. I've got an App component that does a get API request to populate the page with property cards. My Properties component renders a sidebar to filter those cards. The links within that sidebar are making the right API calls, and getting the right response – but that response isn't causing the App component to re-render with fewer properties.

I presume I need a ComponentDidUpdate method in App, or to expand the ComponentDidUpdate method in Properties, but I'm not sure which. Can someone point me in the right direction?

**App component**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      properties: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/PropertyListing')
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          properties: response.data,
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="navigation">
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Properties} />
          <Route exact path="/add-property" component={AddProperty} />
        </Switch>
        <PropertyCards
          properties={this.state.properties}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Properties component**

```
class Properties extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      properties: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { search } = this.props.location;

    if (prevProps.location.search !== search) {
      Axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/PropertyListing${search}`)
        .then(({ data: properties }) => this.setState({ properties }))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sidebar">
        <h4>Filter by city</h4>
        <div className="filters">
          <Link className="filter" to={'/?query={"city":"Manchester"}'}>Manchester</Link>
          <Link className="filter" to={'/?query={"city":"Leeds"}'}>Leeds</Link>
          <Link className="filter" to={'/?query={"city":"Sheffield"}'}>Sheffield</Link>
          <Link className="filter" to={'/?query={"city":"Liverpool"}'}>Liverpool</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general it would be a good idea to move the second api request up intro your parent component, so you 'Properties' component becomes a 'dumb' component which only renders ui according to the data that is passed. That way you don't have to maintain multiple states.

In that context it would definitely make sense to move ComponentDidUpdate() to your 'App' component as well.

Comment: Thanks for getting back on this, Fabian – really appreciate it. I take your point, but as soon as I move ComponentDidUpdate from Properties to App – I get an error saying "search is undefined".

Comment: You need to pass a method to your routes which allow them to update the state of your App component `<Route
  path='/'
  component={Properties}
  setLocation={this.setLocation}
/>`

Comment: Still getting the exact same error, even passing that method!